# Decently close multithread c++ app when receiving SIGINT action

Tags: c++, signals

I'm making a multithreaded c++ application using sockets.
In other words, I have a lot of objects to close (e.g my server socket, close my threads etc).

I usually close everything from the end of my main() function but I can't close everything in a decent way when my app user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

By the way, I could hold all my instances as `static` and close them handling `SIGINT` signal in a static function, but that doesnt sound decent for me, since I have a lot of instances to close..

I was about to send by capture all my instances with sigaction or signal, but it can't compile.

```
signal(SIGINT, [myInstance](int) { myInstance.close() };
```

Indeed, add an instance to anonymous function captures changes the signature and makes it not a function anymore..

Is there any other decent way for do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Make a global atomic flag, set it inside of signal handler and check it outside of signal handler on reasonable intervals during program execution.

Comment: Why not, maybe is there another way? This requires to create another thread

Comment: No this does not require to create any additional threads.

Comment: Well, how then? Since I have to check the flag in a while and run my program in parallel

Comment: Just place the check somewhere in the program code. Check and program execution must not happen in parallel. like `while(!need_to_exit){do_work_chunk();} `

Answer (score 1):

Write your program with an event driven core.

This event driven core usually spends time doing nothing, waiting on new event.

When you recieve SIGINT, simply communicate to *that* event driven core that the signal has arrived.  Then let it cleanly shut down and exit main.

Comment: I dont got you with "event driven core". Can't find any related topic on google

Comment: @mrsmith most interactive apps use this pattern.  It is usually implemented with an event loop.  Sigint is a kind of interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on Linux (or some other POSIX system).

Then read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) (on Linux C++11 [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)-s are implemented above pthreads). Read also POSIX [signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) and some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads).

Notice that signals and threads do not play nice together.

A well known trick is to set up some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (to self) at initialization time and to have your signal handler [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) something on that pipe, and have your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) handling that pipe input and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)-ing it. This is suggested and explained even by Qt in its [*Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) page.

You probably want to use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (not [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)) and you need to provide a raw function (not some `std::function` or lambda expression) - preferably an `extern "C"` one (to be sure that the compiler is using C calling conventions for your signal handler).

You could consider (for `SIGINT` & `SIGTERM`) using the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

You might prefer to avoid handling signals and use some other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facility (maybe [JSONRPC](http://jsonrpc.org/) above [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), or maybe [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) by using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) and make your application a [web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application)) to ask your program to gently terminate.

Answer (score 0):

First off, have a look at boost::asio, if you haven't already. It is a great library that makes networking so much easier.
As to your question: Object oriented design will probably help you a lot. Don't use the socket API directly. But without having any more concrete info (examples, snippets) of your application or your background it is difficult to recommend anything specific. Here are a few ideas:

Catching SIGINT and then terminating the application is really not much different from having a while loop in the main function waiting for a key press. It is simply another way of ending the application.

Write a server class. Write a connection class. Instantiate new connections on the heap and use a shared_ptr (use make_shared). Keep a list of active connection objects. Write a shutdown method for your server class iterating over these objects and closing them. Instantiate one server object per listening socket in main (that way you can easily have a dual stack application, listening on an IP4 and another on an IP6 socket). Have a separate thread for each server and one for each connection (Caveat: this is slow when you have hundreds or thousands of active connections simultaneously).

Study boost::asio examples. There are some great examples that do what you want. Also, boost::asio can work as an "event driven core", as the other answer rightly suggests.

Use RAII (Resource Aquisition Is Initialization) as much as possible.

When you catch SIGINT, simply call server::shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Best way to handle it like below,
#include <signal.h>
void signalfunction(int num)
{
  std::cout << "The interrupt is triggered: " << num << std:endl;
  exit(num);
}
int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, signalfunction);
  while (1) 
  {
    std::cout << "signal uninterrupted...\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```